# How to highlight the current page in the nav menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, pages, css

I'm customizing a WordPress theme for my school, and I'm a bit annoyed by the fact that the current page in the nav menu is not indicated.

For example:

[image]

You can clearly see that I'm hovering over a page in the nav menu, and that the page I'm hovering over is highlighted, as expected.

However, the page that I'm currently on, called "Arhiva", is not highlighted, and I think that this can be somewhat confusing.

I don't want the current page and the page the mouse is hovering over to be highlighed in the same manner though. I believe that a bold entry text in the nav menu would do just fine to separate the current page from other pages.

How can I achieve this?

Theme's current CSS can be viewed here: http://petagimnazija.hr/wp/wp-content/themes/chiron/style.css.

Comment: Does it not work at all or for specific page(s)? Meaning is it broken or not implemented in first place in your theme?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not implemented in the theme. But it should be trivial if WordPress provides the appropriate classes to me, right? (Please don't tell me it doesn't.)

Comment: Well, had you looked for them?.. :) Your site seems to be using custom menus and they seem to have appropriate classes like `current-menu-item` fine...

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks @Rarst. If you'd put that in an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. I just forgot to look for those classes... SE makes you dumber in some cases :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Navigation Menus system is adding a lot of classes, including matching current page (rather intelligently, it will even try to detect custom URLs, that were input explicitly).

The simplest class to make use of is `current-menu-item`, but there are quite a few more dealing with parents/ancestors and more.

Codex has them documented at [`wp_nav_menu()` > Menu Item CSS Classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes).